# Histogram using edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks, charts

I have a `list` of directed edges:

```
list={1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
3 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
3 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
4 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
5 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 
5 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 
7 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
8 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 
8 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 
10 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
11 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
11 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 
12 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 12 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 13 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 
13 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 13 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 13 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 
14 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 15 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 15 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 
16 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 17 \[DirectedEdge] 17};
```

I want to draw a histogram in the following structure. The `list` above consists of In- and Out-links, and I like to construct a histogram combining both In and Out link numbers with different colors in the bars of the histogram. For example, if 5 links go out of vertex 1 and 10 links come in to vertex 1, the bar associated with vertex 1 should have a height of 15. But then, I should be able to see the bars in two colors to visualize the In and Out sample.

I know that `Degree`, `InDegree` and `OutDegree` are the related functions for calculating the data that will be used in constructing the histogram, but I have no idea how I put them in the above structure.

The ideal (limited with my knowledge) solution is to write a `Mathematica` function, the argument of which is a list of directed edges.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated to return chart of loop-free part**

You can use [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart) for this (incorporating halmir's suggestions):

```
inOutGraph[e_] := With[{g = SimpleGraph @ Graph[Sort @ VertexList[e], e]},
    BarChart[
        Transpose @ Through @ {VertexInDegree, VertexOutDegree} @ g,
        ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
    ]
]

inOutGraph[list]
```

> [image]

or:

```
inOutGraph[e_] := With[{g = SimpleGraph @ Graph[Sort @ VertexList[e], e]},
    BarChart[
        Transpose @ Through @ {VertexInDegree, Minus @* VertexOutDegree} @ g,
        ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
    ]
]

inOutGraph[list]
```

> [image]

Comment: Very nice. You even chose the colors I was imagining. Thanks.

Comment: The BarChart does not appear to have the vertices in order. E.g. `3` has 1 in and 6 out but your chart shows a total of 5 for `3` instead if 7..

Comment: @Edmund Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Edmund: Yes, I was about to post the same question you raised.

Comment: @Edmund just define g = Graph[Range[17], list] and use it.

Comment: and for simple graph, apply SimpleGraph to g : SimpleGraph[g]

Answer (score 7):

```
g1 = SimpleGraph @ Graph[Range[17], list];
{ind, outd} = Through[{VertexInDegree, VertexOutDegree}[g1]];
```

#### GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart

```
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[g1, Automatic -> {ind, outd}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Yellow}, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 VertexSize -> .75, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 ChartLegends -> {"VertexInDegree", "VertexOutDegree"}]
```

[image]

Add the options `PolarGridLines->False` and  `PolarAxes->False` to get

[image]

#### [`PairedBarChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PairedBarChart.html)

```
PairedBarChart[Style[#, ColorData[97][1]] & /@ ind, 
 Style[#, ColorData[97][2]] & /@ outd, BarSpacing -> {3, 0, 0}, 
 BarOrigin -> Top, ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[17], Axis]]
```

[image]

#### [`PairedHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PairedHistogram.html) + [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html)

```
PairedHistogram[Style[WeightedData[Range@17, ind], ColorData[97][1]], 
 Style[WeightedData[Range@17, outd],  ColorData[97][2]], 17, 
 BarSpacing -> 3, BarOrigin -> Top, Axes -> {False, True}, 
 Epilog -> (Text[#, {#, 0}] & /@ Range[17])]
```

[image]

Comment: It is really excellent. I am amazed with your extended and very useful answers, which answered many other questions of mine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tugrul, my pleasure.

Comment: With n=17 (number of vertices) a single vertex can have max of 32 links, excluding self loops. Can we set the size of the circle in your 1st polar histogram to `2(n-1)=32` so that I can easily identify those sectors performing the best in the given digraph? Thanks.

Comment: @Tugrul, it should be possible but it seems to be non-trivial (several things I tried with `PolarAxes`, `PolarGridLines` ... did not give the desired result.)

Comment: Thank you for your trials. I appreciate it. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

With ordered vertices

```
vl = VertexList@list;
degree = Association @@ Thread[{"In", "Out"} -> Through@{VertexInDegree, VertexOutDegree}@list];
degree = #[[Ordering[vl]]] & /@ degree;
vl = vl[[Ordering[vl]]];

BarChart[Transpose@Values@degree,
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLabels -> {vl, None},
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, {"In", "Out"}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: and @Carl: Would be possible to exclude `SelfLoops` from the histogram?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with ordered vertices, and self-loops removed:

```
listToCounts[list_] := Module[{l2, maxvertex, goingout, goingin},
   l2 = DeleteCases[list, (a_ \[DirectedEdge] a_)];
   maxvertex = Max[{l2[[All, 1]], l2[[All, 2]]}];
   goingout = Table[Count[l2[[All, 1]], vertex], {vertex, maxvertex}];
   goingin = Table[Count[l2[[All, 2]], vertex], {vertex, maxvertex}];
   Transpose[{goingin, goingout}]
   ];

counts = listToCounts[list]
```

> {{1, 1}, {3, 0}, {0, 5}, {1, 0}, {2, 6}, {0, 15}, {3, 1}, {4, 5}, {11,0}, {2, 1}, {4, 6}, {1, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 0}}

```
BarChart[counts, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLegends -> {"in", "out"}, ChartStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, ChartLabels -> {ToString[#] & /@ Range[Max[{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2]]}]], None}]
```

[image]